# Alias, domain and redirect to website/web application

Tags: redirect, iis, networking, dns, alias

It might sound a very naive and stupid, but I'm not that strong in networking.
I have a website lets it has the following domain name https://website.com
It is added to the DNS and accessible. However I need to create an alias called "website" so that when the user type "website/" to the browser, he/she will be redirected to https://website.com. 
the question how do I do that? Can I do that at the IIS since my application is installed on the IIS? Or is there any other way to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use website/ as an alias to domain name website.com **over the internet**.